# AJAX passing variable issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi all Im trying to pass form data and an additional variable using an AJAX call as seen below:

```
function tempFunction(obj) {
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();
    data.push(
        {
            no: $(obj).attr('id')
        }
    );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/tempproject/main/changepage",
        data: data,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

however in PHP when I try and call back the 'no' variable I am getting an error saying undefined index.
within my php file I am trying:

```
$test  = $_POST['no'];
echo $test;
```

when clicking I receive a popup that says undefined index no.

Comment: check in development tool of browser what data its sending..

Comment: or do a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I will do and post the result - many thanks

Comment: `serializeArray()` (http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns array in the format: [{name: "name",value: "name"},...]. So your `push()` call is wrong.

Comment: ^it seems that way Im getting a perfect array up until the push data where it is listed as undefined

Comment: thanks for the help troubleshooting guys much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the array is an object with a name and value property:

Try like this:

```
data.push({name: 'no', value: $(obj).attr('id')});
```

Comment: Thanks very much best answer worked - and cheers to the guys that suggested dumping the contents of post I'm so newb I didn't even think of it thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Datas should be passed within `{}` like this in ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/tempproject/main/changepage",
        data: "{no: " + $(obj).attr('id') + "}",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this will keep your form values

```
function tempFunction(obj) {

  var data = $('form').serialize(); 
  data += '&no='.$(obj).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/tempproject/main/changepage",
        data: data,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```